# WebHDFS/HttpFS in CDH via Docker

Tags: docker, hadoop, webhdfs, httpfs

i'm using cloudera quickstart via Docker Toolbox (docker for win10 home).
The CDH version is 5.7

i'm trying to connect to hdfs with Webhdfs/HttpFS, i dont sure if the port is 50070 or 14000. [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cdh_ig_ports_cdh5.html) is the list of ports in CDH 5.7

1) I'm actualy dont sure what is the user name i need to use with i tried root, cloudera or maybe its the name of the container?
[try to connect with CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJXST.png)

2) I've tried those examples and got the same errors ([example1](https://dzone.com/articles/hadoop-rest-api-webhdfs), [example2](https://bighadoop.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/hadoop-rest-api-webhdfs/))

thanks

Comment: Are you talking about accessing a service running in docker from another docker container, or from the host? Issuing the command `docker ps` from a command line should give you an idea of what ports you've exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  Engineer Dollery 2.
I created a new container and expose the port of WebHDFS and now its working.
The port of WebHDFS in CDH 5.7 is 14000 (not 50070 as was before).
The username was cloudera but i dont sure its necessary.